I want to edit word document with php i am getting output but i not changing data
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Capture form data
    $formData = [
      'trademark_no' => $_POST['trademark'] ?? '123456',
      'trademark_name' => $_POST['trademarkname'] ?? 'Abc Trademark',
  ];

    // Load the template
    $templatePath = './data/Temp.docx';
    $templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor($templatePath);

    // Replace placeholders in the template
    $templateProcessor->setValue('Trademark_Number', $formData['trademark_no']);

    echo "Trademark_Number Placeholder Value: " . $formData['trademark_no'] . "<br>";


    // Save the generated document
    $outputPath = './affidavits/generated_affidavit1.docx';
    $templateProcessor->saveAs($outputPath);

    echo "Affidavit generated successfully. <a href='$outputPath'>Download here</a>";
} else {
    // Display the form if not a POST request
}


This is my template word file snap.
I am expecting change trademark number in generated docx file but i am facing probelm it not changing value can you tell me what is the problem??
